# Problem translate text that's inside an image with OCR, pytesseract and opencv in Python and write the translated text back into the img (same pos)

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, translation, python-tesseract

I'm working on a project about OCR translation in python. I'm trying to write a script that takes a web page full of images with some text in them. Through OCR it will detect text that will be translated and, then, it will write the translated text over the original one. This project focus on translate webcomics (precisely text inside dialogue baloons).
I will try to explain it better, sorry for my English. So, my idea was to do an HTML request to get the content of a webpage. Then convert it into a PDF file. Next split the PDF into multiple PNGs. After that, circle every single PNG to: 1) scan the image to find words 2) store positions of those words 3) take those words and translate them 4) take the translated ones and put them over the originals using stored positions. After all the PNGs have their text replaced and, so, translated, I will merge them into a new final pdf. My problem is that I cannot do the OCR part. Also I have no idea how can I store original text position and then write something over it using that position.
I'm doing my best as a python newbie.

I've done the HTML request and the convert into PDF file part:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pdfkit

url = "https://example.com"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

try:
    pdfkit.from_string(str(soup), 'page.pdf', configuration=pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'), options={'enable-local-file-access': ''})
except IOError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
    pass
```

I also have done the split into PNGs part:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pdf_path = "page.pdf"

images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    image.save("pages/page_{}.png".format(i), "PNG")
```

As for now, it all work. The next point was to track the text with OCR and store its position but I do not know how to do it. I searched online but I couldn't find what I needed. So, with my last hope, I tried OpenAI GPT3 to see if the famous AI could find something. It gave me this code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread("page_1.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

h, w, _ = img.shape
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)
for b in boxes.splitlines():
    b = b.split(' ')
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[1]), h - int(b[2])), (int(b[3]), h - int(b[4])), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result is impressive but it's not what I need. It just create rettangles around letters and other lines.
[result of gpt script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf1DL.png)

So with this I tried to modify the code. I also rewrote it from the start but nothing. The best I could do with its help was random text all over the img.
[result of last script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWScp.png)

Also I have already done the translation part that will be needed in the future (yes I'm trying to translate English to Italian):

```
from googletrans import Translator
def translate_text(text):
    translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])
    translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest='it').text
    return translated_text
```

Next I will be doing the "multiple PNGs back into one PDF file" but I think I can do that. As already explained, my problem is the OCR part. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: `pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)` gives you the location of each letter in your picture. It's up to you to process that data to see if you can pick out words. It looks like `image_to_data` might give you location of words. Documentation [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract)  is difficult to decipher. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempt to do it from scratch, it is considered easier to use an OCR app to do the conversion in one or two steps. So sending PDF for translation from English to Italian  will look like this one as done via Google.

[image]

HOWEVER there are so many problems with automated translation especially in PDF since the Word order is often drastically changed and the source imagery is usually still there.

[image]

So when sending the source PDF the image needs to be redacted first, as it's so much harder work to do it later, that it would be easier to just cut and paste the translations as desired.

[image]